# Clear current attachment's data and input new data everytime I send email

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

Currently my email function is working and is able to send an attachment every time I click the button.

However every time I send an email, the data is just added to what is already in the file.
I was just wondering if it is possible to clear the test.html data inside then input the new data inside.

```
string attachmentBody = "Testing 1 2 3";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.html", true, Encoding.UTF8);
sw.Write(attachmentBody);
sw.Close();
ttachment data = new Attachment("Test.html");
mailObj.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're passing true to append param (take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/36b035cb.aspx) for StreamWriter constructor syntax).
Try this:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.html", false, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Good catch.  My answer was the wrong way to go about things, so I've deleted it.

Comment: Thanks @MerlynMorgan-Graham; anyway I don't think downvoting you was correct because your answer was not wrong.

Comment: Thanks Marco! Now it works! really thank you!

Thanks to @MerlynMorgan-Graham for your answers too! It works too! :)